# content popup with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have content which is sliding down when clicked on heading using jquery. But i want to open content popup instead of sliding.  I tried google but didn't succeed(coz new to jquery).

So my question is what is best & simplest way to pop up content(should be supported in all/ most of the devices and browsers).

```
<p class="heading" style="background-color:#007BB6; color: #fff !important;"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <br><br><img id="bg" src="images/down.png"/> </p>
    <div class="content" style="background-color:#e5f1f7; text-align:justify;">
    <p style="margin-top:0;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent viverra viverra lectus sed feugiat. In rutrum orci sit amet purus dapibus, eget ultricies odio consequat. Aenean semper pretium tellus eget cursus. Sed eget finibus orci. Ut fermentum enim
    quis quam rhoncus pretium.
```

Jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/345hxhx7/

appreciate the help!

Comment: You can use confirm box for popup.

Comment: You're going to have to define exactly what you mean by "pop up" in this case; as you can see with a question this vague you're going to get answers all over the map (so far you've got the gamut from "throw gigantic UI libraries at the problem" to "pop a confirm dialog")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have simple jQuery solution. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sarowerj/345hxhx7/5/)  {{Edited}}

New HTML:

```
<div class="pop_up" data-status="close"> 
   <div class="pop_overlay"></div>
   <div class="pop_wrapper">
       <div class="pop_title">
            The Title 
            <span class="pop_close">X</span>
       </div>
       <div class="pop_content">
            Popup Content will come here;
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

The jQuery

```
jQuery(".heading").click(function() {
    var this_item = jQuery(this).attr('data-item');
    var item_cont = jQuery('#'+this_item).html();
    jQuery('.pop_up').fadeIn();
    jQuery('.pop_content').html(item_cont);
    jQuery(".pop_close,.pop_overlay").click(function() {
        jQuery('.pop_up').fadeOut();
    });
});
```

New CSS

```
.pop_up{
    display:none;
}
.pop_overlay{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    position:fixed;
  }
  .pop_wrapper{
      max-width:450px;
      margin:auto;
      box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
      position:relative;
      z-index:9999;
      position:fixed;
      left:0;
      right:0;
      top:100px;
  }
  .pop_wrapper .pop_title{
      padding:10px;
      background:#fafafa;
  }
  .pop_content{
      background:white;
      padding:15px;
  }
  .pop_close{
      float:right;
  }
```

Check my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sarowerj/345hxhx7/5/) demo.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery UI's [Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) or Boostrap's [Modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at jPopup: https://github.com/seahorsepip/jPopup

Supports all browsers(ie7+) and is mobile friendly, whatever you want, there's an option for that. Lot's of positions, changing the offset, changing settings and content even after the popup has opened.